# Invoking CPU Stress

Tags: cpu, benchmark

Looking for an app or tool to invoke CPU usage on my virtual Linux and Unix guests.
I found the app "stress" from a [post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141707/how-to-set-cpu-load-on-a-red-hat-linux-box), but curious what the Unix/Linux crowd would recommend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goto for Linux is `cpuburn` ([homepage](http://freecode.com/projects/cpuburn)). I would expect that it should work on other UNIX systems as well.

Comment: TY sir, this gives me something else to compare my data with.

Comment: as of 2022, the link posted here to *freecode* is out of date.  cpuburn can be found at `https://patrickmn.com/projects/cpuburn/` providing `cpuburn-1.0-amd64.tar.gz`

Answer (score 5):

`stress` is pretty good. I see no reason to use something else.

```
stress --cpu 6 --timeout 10
```

Comment: Stress is just about perfect, I ultimately need an alternative to compare data against.

Answer (score 2):

I think `cpuburn` and `stress` are good, but I also have python script that I use to additional stress.

```
import multiprocessing
import math

def worker():
    #worker function
    print ('Worker')
    x = 0
    while x < 1000000000000000000:

        print(x)
        p = x*math.pi
        p2 = math.sqrt(x**2 + p**2)
        print(p2)

        x += 1
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(50):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Comment: According to the stress man-page this is pretty much the same what stress does...

Answer (score 2):

I've been developing stress-ng, which provides a wide range of stress mechanisms.  See http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/stress-ng/

stress-ng is now available in Debian 8 and Ubuntu 14.04. It tries to be backwardly compatible with stress but is a clean re-write. stress-ng will stress test a computer system in various selectable ways. It was designed to exercise various physical subsystems of a computer as well as the various operating system kernel interfaces. Stress-ng features: over 120 different stress tests over 50 CPU specific stress tests that exercise floating point, integer, bit manipulation and control flow over 20 virtual memory stress tests

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Can you expand this answer a bit? Perhaps by adding a usage of your tool along with some example output? Answers on SE sites generally need to be more than just a link.

Comment: stress-ng is now available in Debian 8 and Ubuntu 14.04. It tries to be backwardly compatible with stress but is a clean re-write.  stress-ng will stress test a computer system in various selectable ways. It was designed to exercise various physical subsystems of a computer as well as the various operating system kernel interfaces. Stress-ng features:

    over 80 different stress tests
    over 50 CPU specific stress tests that exercise floating point, integer, bit manipulation and control flow
    over 20 virtual memory stress tests

Comment: can you please put that in your answer? Link only answers are typically discouraged and are often deleted if no details are incorporated into them.